# Does a child who is adopted by a Kohen inherit Kohen status?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, kohen-priest

Would such a child (non Jewish) who is adopted and converts inherit any status from his father? Has any posek ruled on this? Is there halacha for this?

Comment: You mean [if his mother was not Jewish and his father was a Kohen](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48892/can-one-be-a-kohen-without-being-jewish)?

Comment: Is the question about conversion or adoption? And why would you think either of them has an effect on one's status as a Kohen?

Answer (score 2):

No. Kohen status is patrilinear. See Shulchan Aruch Even HaEzer chapters 1, 2, 3, 4, and 6.

Comment: "Have rabbis ruled on this?" Yes, rabbis have gotten this question before. A lot. In the "bad old days" when people tried to pass off adopted children as biological ones (and the kid themselves often didn't know), the kohen issue was a tricky one. Similarly if dad's a kohen and mom's a convert (or not Jewish at all, but they converted the kids) -- kids are not kohanim, but sometimes the dad wanted to save face and tried pressuring the rabbi. Not a good situation.

Comment: If Dad’s a kohen and Mom had already converted at the time of birth, then child is a kohen at least for some purposes